# Xcode 4.2 and Facebook SDK 3.0 tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, osx-snow-leopard, facebook-ios-sdk

I need facebook integration for my ios app. I am on OS X Snow Leopard & cannot upgrade my OS/Xcode at this point. All tutorials on the web seem to focus on Facbook SDK 3.1 integration (which needs me to upgrade my Xcode).

I tried this [tutorial](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html), (yes I "Linked Binary With Libraries" for FacebookSDK.framework & Accounts.framework.

`But I get the error "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" file not found`

Can someone point me to a documentation/tutorial for integrating **Facebook SDK 3.0** with **ios app on Xcode 4.2**? I need login/authenticate & invite friends functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Comment: @Sapan Thats the first place I checked. The tutorials there are for Facbook SDK 3.1.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is only 1 getting started section in that link & that points to 3.1 SDK.    
 "Install the Prerequisites" states "You need Xcode 3.5"

Here is the link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Answer (score 0):

FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h is part of Deprecated headers. Add Deprecated Headers to your project and rebuild your application. It should work fine.